# How to apply dynamic filters in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter

I'm starting to learn AngularJS now and I have some issues with filters.
I need to apply two types of filters and I can't figure out how.

I have a device list JSON that looks like this:

```
[{
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Device 1",
    "Price": 1998.92,
    "Colors": [{
        "ColorCode": "Red",
        "ColorName": "#FF0000"
    },
    {
        "ColorCode": "Green",
        "ColorName": "#2EFE2E"
    }],
    "Type": {
        "TypeID": 1,
        "TypeName": "Mobile device"
    },
    "Company": {
        "CompanyID": 1,
        "CompanyName": "Alcatel"
    }
}]
```

I display the list like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="device in devices | filter:companyFilters | filter:colorFilters">
    <span>{{device.Company.CompanyID}}</span> // 1
    <span>{{device.Company.CompanyName}}</span> // Google
    <span>{{device.Name}}</span> // Nexus 6P
</div>
```

I have some filters that I applied but there are two filters that I can't understand how to apply.

Filter 1:

- A checkbox list of companies that filters the items by the selected
  companies.

Filter 2:

- A color filter that when clicking on a color will filter the devices
  that has that color

For the company filter I have this checkbox list:

```
<div ng-repeat="company in deviceCompanies">
    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="companyFilters" id="{{company.CompanyID}}" data-ng-true-value='{{company.CompanyID}}' data-ng-false-value='' />
    <label for="{{company.CompanyID}}">{{company.CompanyName}}</label>
</div>
```

And on the controller side I have this:

```
$scope.companyFilters = [];
```

For the color filter I have this:

```
<div>
    <a ng-click="???">All</a>
    <div ng-repeat="color in deviceColors" style="display:inline-block; margin-right:10px;">
        <div style="width:20px;height:20px;background-color:{{color.ColorCode}}"></div>
        <a ng-model="selColor" data-ng="color.ColorCode" ng-click="colorFilters">{{color.ColorName}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And on the controller:

```
$scope.colorFilters = function (device) {
        if (!$scope.selColor)
            return true;
        for (var i = 0; i < device.Colors.length; i++) {
            if (device.Colors[i].ColorCode == $scope.selColor)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
```

But it doesn't work...
Can anyone please tell me how to apply these filters ?

Comment: filter on `ng-repeat` needs to take in the full array and return new filtered array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some workarounds, this is what I came up with:

```
<div ng-repeat="company in deviceCompanies">
    <!--the ng-click will call a function that updated an array of values-->
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{company.CompanyID}}" ng-click="selectCompany(company.CompanyID)">
    <label for="{{company.CompanyID}}">{{company.CompanyName}}</label>
</div>
```

And the controller part is so simple:

```
$scope.selectedCompanies = [];
//when the array is upted the filter function will also launch
$scope.selectCompany = function (companyId) {
    var i = $.inArray(companyId, $scope.selectedCompanies);
    if (i > -1) {
        $scope.selectedCompanies.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
        $scope.selectedCompanies.push(companyId);
    }
}

$scope.companyFilter = function (device) {
    if ($scope.selectedCompanies.length > 0) {
        if ($.inArray(device.Company.CompanyID, $scope.selectedCompanies) < 0)
            return;
    }

    return device;
}
```

Same goes to the colors filter:

```
<div>
    <a ng-click="selectColor()">All</a>
    <div ng-repeat="color in deviceColors" style="display:inline-block; margin-right:10px;">
        <div style="width:20px;height:20px;background-color:{{color.ColorCode}}"></div>
        <a ng-click="selectColor(color.ColorCode)">{{color.ColorName}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And controller part:

```
$scope.selectedColor;

$scope.selectColor = function (colorCode) {
    $scope.selectedColor = colorCode;
}

$scope.colorFilters = function (device) {
    if (!$scope.selectedColor)
        return true;
    for (var i = 0; i < device.Colors.length; i++) {
        if (device.Colors[i].ColorCode == $scope.selectedColor)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

And finally, applying the filters:

```
<div ng-repeat="device in devices | filter:companyFilter | filter:colorFilters">
    ...
</div>
```

You can have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/65Pyj/) to see how it works

I think the color filter can be more elegant, but, for now, this does the trick.

If I'll come up with a better solution I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ng-repeat which creates its own scope, anything you do in ng-repeat will not get recognized on the controller scope. Using a tool like ng-inspector or batarang will illustrate this.

I recommend using controllerAs Syntax, in your controller add.

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('CustomFilterController', function() {
  var vm = this;
  this.devices = //your list of data
  this.companyFilters = [];
  this.colorFilters = //your function
}
```

On your view declare your controller like this:

```
 <div ng-controller='CustomFilterController as custom'>
```

(Note the value after as can be whatever you want it to be)

Then reference anything on that controller as custom.ThingOnController

EX:

```
<div ng-repeat="device in custom.devices | filter:custom.companyFilters | filter:custom.colorFilters">
```

Comment: I updated the answer to better illustrate how to update the controller. Which parts are you having trouble with? That way the answer can be better in case others have a similar problem.